# Javascript | How to convert a timestamp string from different timezone to Date object, without changing the time to OS timezone?

Tags: javascript, time

In Javascript, converting the following string `2022-01-07T17:12:41.494473144-05:00` to a `Date` object results in a Date object with value `2022-01-07T22:18:44.614Z`.

Trimming the String to `2022-01-07T17:12:41.494473144` results in a Date object with value `2022-01-07T16:12:41.494Z`

Expected result in both cases are a Date object with value `2022-01-07 17:12:41`.

**Question:** How can I convert the above string representation of a timestamp to a Date object, regardless of the clock/timezone of the operating system executing the code?

Comment: Maybe the [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) methods

Comment: I'm not sure you can. A Date-object in JavaScript will *always* have a timezone. When you don't supply a timezone, the default OS timezone will have to suffice. 

It is important to note that 2022-01-07T17:12:41.494473144-05:00 and 2022-01-07T17:12:41.494473144 are *inherently two different dates*, and they should not be equal.

Comment: If you want a string-representation of 2022-01-07 17:12:41 without a timezone, you could use [dayjs](https://day.js.org/), which makes formatting quite simple.

Comment: @HenrikKlev, can you please provide an example of using dayjs?